# Compiler Error "void value not ignored as it ought to be" in C programming

Tags: c, compiler-errors, return-value

I got that error which cant figure out. I look over related questions but I dont give a meaning someone show me which part do I need to fix?

> [Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be

My codes

```
void getEdge(char str[],char *token){
    *token = strtok(str, "_,");
    while (token != NULL )
    {
      //  printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, "_,");
    }

}

void getEdge(char str[],char *token);

int main () {
    char arr[] = "A_B_10,A_F_6,B_C_6,C_B_10,D_A_3";
    char *toke;
    char result;
    result = getEdge(arr,toke);
    printf("%s\n",result);

}
```

Comment: You've declared `getEdge` to not return anything yet you still want to store it's return value in a variable. Change your function declaration and return the result from your function.

Comment: @Li357 thank you for you advise. I wil try..

Comment: What output do you expect? What output do you get? In case you want the output you got by printing within `getEdge()`, then you need quite a complex return value to be able to retrieve it with a single `return ...;`.

Comment: What compiler is this? The error wording seems a bit *different*.

Comment: It's a little odd to declare the function after you've defined.  Harmless, but not necessary.

Answer (score 11):

Check this line

```
 result = getEdge(arr,toke);
```

you're trying to capture the return value of a function for which the return type is `void`.

Remember, `void` is an incomplete type, and it's not compatible with any other type (in this case, LHS is `char`), hence the compiler rightly complains.

That said,

```
*token = strtok(str, "_,");
```

inside the function also does not look very correct. Check the types there.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are declaring a function without a return value:

```
void getEdge(char str[],char *token)
```

And here you are working with a function which returns a char-value

```
char result;
result = getEdge(arr,toke);
```

So a solution could be to change your function in:

```
char getEdge(char str[],char *token)
{
    ......
    return char_value;
}
```